# Compute $\int \sqrt{1+4x^2} \, dx$ with Euler substitution

Tags: integration

In this post:
[Computing $\int \sqrt{1+4x^2} \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056058/computing-int-sqrt14x2-dx)
someone mentioned Euler substitution to compute the following integral:

$$\int \sqrt{1+4x^2} \, dx$$

I tried to follow this advice and got very nice result, namely I substituted $\sqrt{1+4x^2}=t-2x$ which after raising to the square and reducing gives $x=\frac{t^2-1}{4t}$ and $t-2x=\frac{t^2+1}{2t}$, then derivative is equal to $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{t^2+1}{4t^2}$ and the whole integral:

$$\int \sqrt{1+4x^2} \, dx = \int \frac{(t^2+1)^2}{8t^3} \, dt$$

Could you please check my solution, because it seems a lot easier than all these trigonometric substitution (too easy which is suspicious...).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set $\sqrt{1+4x^2}=t-2x$, you have
$$
1+4x^2=t^2-4tx+4x^2
$$
so $4tx=t^2-1$ and therefore
$$
x=\frac{t^2-1}{4t}=\frac{t}{4}-\frac{1}{4t}
$$
Thus
$$
dx=\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4t^2}\right)\,dt=\frac{t^2+1}{4t^2}\,dt
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{1+4x^2}=t-\frac{t}{2}+\frac{1}{2t}=\frac{t^2+1}{2t}
$$
so the integral becomes
$$
\int\frac{(t^2+1)^2}{8t^3}\,dt=
\frac{1}{8}\int\left(t+\frac{2}{t}+\frac{1}{t^3}\right)\,dt
$$
that's elementary.

Yes, your computation is right.

---

The alternative way is setting $2x=\sinh(t/2)$, so
$$
\sqrt{1+4x^2}=\cosh\frac{t}{2},
\qquad
dx=\frac{1}{4}\cosh\frac{t}{2}\,dt
$$
and the integral is
$$
\frac{1}{4}\int\cosh^2\frac{t}{2}\,dt=
\frac{1}{8}\int(\cosh t-1)\,dt
$$
remembering that $2\cosh^2\frac{t}{2}+1=\cosh t$.

---

Another (tricky) way is to do $2x=t$, that reduces to computing, up to a scalar factor,
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\arsinh}{arsinh}
I=\int\sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt=\int\frac{1+t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt=
\arsinh t+\int t\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt=
\arsinh t+t\sqrt{1+t^2}-I
$$
(the last one by parts).

Comment: I took the liberty of making some slight changes in the first part of your answer, but please feel free to change them again if I made any mistakes.

Comment: @user84413 Thanks, the fix seems more correct than the original. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$x=\frac{1}{2}\tan\theta$$
$$I=\frac12\int\sec^3\theta\,d\theta $$