# Given its arc length, what is the shape of a parabola?

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, curves, arc-length

> A chain of length $k$ is hung between two fixed walls of $2x$ distance apart.  How low does the chain hang (at its lowest point)?  Assume the chain makes a parabola (not a catenary).

This is the reverse question of the [classic problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622002/if-i-bend-a-straight-line-segment-such-that-the-arc-length-of-the-line-remains-c), which is much easier to solve:

> What is the arc length of a parabola $y = a x^2$ from the origin to the point where $x = x_0$?

This version is straightforward, because $$arc\ length = \int_0^x \sqrt{1+4a^2t^2}\ dt$$ which can also be used to solve the top problem numerically.

However, I realized that *since all parabolas are similar, the $a$ factor in the equation is a bit of a red herring!*  We should be able to scale our units so that the parabola $Y = X^2$ has our answer (for some scaling $r$ such that $Y = ry, X = rx$), which should make it possible to solve the top problem.

I also tried tackling

> A chain is hung between two fixed walls so that it makes a parabola $y_0 = a_0x^2$ with arc length $s_0$.  The chain stretches (e.g. due to heat) by a factor of $h$.  What is the new shape - that is, what is $a_h$ if the curve $y_h = a_hx^2$ has arclength $h \cdot s_0$, given that $x$ is fixed.

I thought this would be easier: since the derivative of arc length with respect to $x$ is clearly $\sqrt{1 + 4a^2x^2}$, we should be able to determine the ration between change in arc length and change in $x$.  But the resultant change in $a$ threw me for a curve (no pun intended).

Can any of these problems be solved analytically (acknowledging that numeric methods can be used for any of them)?

Comment: Your question may be duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4209381/how-to-straighten-a-parabola/4209483#4209483). To invert the $\sinh^{-1}(x)$ expression for the arclength, one may use [this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816307/isolating-x-analytically-in-this-equation-xeaxx-fy/4732155#4732155) if this is needed for the problem

Comment: Do you mean something like $\left(\sqrt a x\right)^2$? We scale $x$ by $k$ and the problem is apparent, $y$ is scaled by $k^2$.